# How to host Django website on oracle cloud virtual machine?

Tags: python, django, virtual-machine, vps

I am trying to host a Django Project on Oracle cloud virtual machine running Ubuntu.

As I am not too experienced with virtual machines, I was following along with this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

What I have succeeded in doing so far is to create postgresql database and starting django project and connecting the database to the django project, and applying migrations. However, as per the tutorial, I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and it appears that the website has been deployed, but upon entering public ip into browser, it says could not connect to the ip. Any help?

I have added ingress rules 8000/udp and 8000/tcp into the subnet but still no luck

Comment: So did you ever find the solution? I'm facing the same  problem.

Comment: yes, i followed these links and was able to fix my issue:

https://kerneltalks.com/virtualization/how-to-reset-iptables-to-default-settings/
https://yoursunny.com/t/2020/OracleCloud-website/#:~:text=Oracle%20Cloud%20has%20a%20strict%20firewall%20that%2C%20by,in%20%22Primary%20VNIC%22%20section%20of%20%22Instance%20Details%22%20page.

For the second link, just follow along until he gets to creating an http server